# How can you kill a task in bash when it times out? (mosquitto_sub)

Tags: bash, process, mosquitto

My task is this, after subscribing to a topic using mosquitto_sub, it is necessary to close the connection or kill the process if there is no answer for more than n seconds. I'm not an expert in bash, please help.

Comment: The [`timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command is part of GNU `coreutils` and will be available on almost all Linux distributions.

Comment: If l can get this reopened I'll answers this properly, but the `-W` and `-c` combined will solve this specifically for `mosquitto_sub` http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html